# Issues adding to ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have watched videos, searched this websites and many others, but nothing really helps. This is the first time I have used ArrayLists. If I have the ArrayList as String it's fine, but as soon as I set Comment (which is the class) it no longer works. But the tutor has implied that this is how it's meant to be used. I have two other classes that need access to it plus obviously the main method.

Main problem I am having is it won't allow me to add to the arraylist. And I'm stumped and it's probably really simple.

```
public class Comment {

// somehow need to link it to the game/app
private ArrayList<Comment> Reply = new ArrayList<Comment>();

private String usrComment;
private String usrID;

public Comment() {
}

public Comment(String usrID, String usrComs) {
    this.usrComment = usrComs;
    this.usrID = usrID;
}

public void addReview(String addRev) {

    this.Reply.add(addRev); // not working
}

public void addReply(String addRep) {

    Reply.add(addRep); // not working and I cannot figure it out
}

public void printRep() {
    for (Comment comment : Reply) {
        System.out.println(comment);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The method add(Comment) in the type ArrayList<Comment> is not applicable for the arguments (String

Comment: Well, it itsn't: you're giving it a string, your list expects `Comment`s.

Comment: Well, read what the compiler must have told you. Your "not working" is in fact "not compilable" and just follow the compiler error message: you cannot assign `String` to `Comment` and vice versa.

Comment: This is where I show my ignorance. Isn't Comment just an object of the Comment class?

Comment: And change the title - your question has nothing to do with `ArrayList` - it is just incompatible types... So your question might be "How to make `Comment` out of `String`"

Comment: Yes, `Comment` is `Comment` and `String` is `String`. You cannot assign them to each other. Apples and orranges. `Reply.add()` method expects an object of the type `Comment` and you are passing it an object of the type `String`. That's the meaning of the error message. You have to convert the object before passing it. It is like you cannot connect HDMI connector into D-Sub connector.

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense. I learn more of this website than I do at uni for Java, it's depressing, especially when you pay through the roof for it. I didn't really know what name to give the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add a `String` but the array list is expecting a `Comment`

```
public void addReview(String addRev) {
    // Reply is an ArrayList<Comment> of Comments not of Strings
    // this.Reply.add(addRev); // not working
    // you can create a new Comment and then add that comment
    this.Reply.add(new Comment("userId", addRev));
}

public void addReply(String addRep) {
    // same here
    // Reply.add(addRep); // not working and I cannot figure it out
    // you can create a new Comment and then add that comment
    this.Reply.add(new Comment("userId", addRep));
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, like I said it's probably really simple. I have a terrible tutor. A lovely person, but she cannot teach. If I had known that at the start I would have saved so much time.

Comment: @NWoods Glad I could help! To be honest, it threw me off a bit because in real life, "comments are strings" haha.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your code to do the following :

```
/**
 *id - ID of the user reviewing the comment
 *review - The review comment made by the user
 */
public void addReview(String id, String review) {
this.Reply.add(new Comment(id,review));
}

/**
 *id - ID of the user replying
 *review - The reply comment made by the user
 */
public void addReply(String id, String reply) {
this.Reply.add(new Comment(id,reply));
}
```

To print the comment, you could add a toString method as follows :

```
public String toString(){
  return "ID : "+this.usrID+", Comment : "+this.usrComment;
}
```

That way, System.out.println(comment); will print :

```
ID : 123412, Comment : This is a comment
```

for an object instantiated like this :

```
Comment comment = new Comment("123412", "This is a comment")
```

Comment: I did that and it worked, but the way the main method is setup it just would work.

Comment: @NWoods I've edited my answer so that you can improve your code slightly. I'd suggest putting this up on https://codereview.stackexchange.com